# Replace n% of words in a text files with random words from another

Tags: python

This is a newbie question. How would I replace n% of words in a text file with random English words. I have the English words in another text file.

I know i can use random.choice() to sample a word at random from the text file, but im not sure how i would use it to actually select the word i want to replace , without replacing all instances of that word. i .e if there are two "the"'s and they are both chosen to be replaced they must be replaced with different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be to split the words into an array:

```
words = list_of_words.split(' ')
```

Then you can replace any word by using its index:

```
words[7] = "newWord"
```

When you're done, join the array back together:

```
' '.join(words)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Nice answer! Only thing I can think of which could improve the answer is if you elaborated slightly more in reference to the randomization and % part that OP was asking about, but I think this piece of information is still very useful to the asker. Nice work.